# Can I setup ADSL modem by connecting it to an optic fibre modem that provides a RJ11 output?

Tags: networking, modem, adsl, fiber, rj-11

Right off the bat I would like to state that I have a very basic understanding of computer networks.

The previous internet setup that I had was - RJ11 cable from the ISP box connected to a D-LINK DSL-2520U modem that was connected to a TP-LINK TL-WR841N Wi-Fi router via RJ45.

The current internet setup I have is - optic fibre cable from the ISP box connected to a Dragonpath 707GR1. This device also provides a RJ11 output to which a telephone is connected.

Since the move to optic fibre the old setup is lying around collecting dust. Hence I would like to know if it is possible to setup the D-LINK ADSL modem through the Dragonpath fibre device via the provided RJ11 connection that the telephone uses currently?

I am very well aware that it is possible to connect the TP-LINK wi-fi device to the Dragonpath fibre modem via RJ45. However, the intention here is to make use of the old D-LINK ADSL modem too if possible.

Comment: "*setup the D-LINK ADSL modem*" -- To do what? There is no ADSL signal anymore to modulate/demodulate! Instead of mentioning just devices and connectors, you need to also think of what those devices do, i.e. what function(s) does each device perform? "*connect the TP-LINK wi-fi device ... via RJ45*" -- RJ-45 is simply a connector (the female connector is aka port), and not a "*connection*". You are presumably referring to an Ethernet connection.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you want to solve? Why are you concerned with trying to forcible use obsolete technology with modern technologies? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: You seem to be conflating connectors such as RJ-11 and RJ-45 with some type of protocol or interface or connection. That is simply incorrect. Only "modern" interfaces, such as USB, SATA, and HDMI, which are controlled/standardized by commercial organizations, use proprietary connectors and define the protocol employed. Older connectors, such as DB-xx and RJ-xx, are somewhat standardized, but there are no assigned protocols and can be used for any variety of connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to question is **No**.

You can't connect the D-LINK ADSL modem to the RJ11 and expect anything to happen on the on the D-LINK device. The ISP doesn't provide an internet signal through that connection.

But to address you're real **concern**: "*the old setup is lying around collecting dust*". It doesn't need to be collecting dust, you can simply dispose of it... That device is an ADSL modem needed for your old copper internet connection, which you don't have anymore. So neither can it do anything useful for you, nor do you need it for anything useful. Everything is working fine without it.

Comment: Thank you for the dignified response. I see that what I hoped to achieve with my utter lack of knowledge is impossible due to the nature of the many technologies involved themselves. I agree that I will need to dispose of a perfectly working modem. Am sure somebody somewhere might need it. The query has been satisfactorily answered. I shall mark it as such! Cheers!!